# How does Virtual DOM in React help in rendering of real DOM in the UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

I am a total beginner in ReactJS, so please excuse if this question is too naive.
What I understand is that since real DOM is structured as a tree, making changes to them are easy, but it's the re-rendering part that affects the performance, especially if you have a lot of changes to render.

So React comes with this idea of virtual DOM, which finds out very efficiently what the changes are and then sends a batch update to the real DOM.

Nevertheless, the DOM still needs to render those changes right? That would mean whatever changes have been done to the virtual DOM, they will all be updated in the actual DOM and rendered.

So how exactly does virtual DOM make it easier? Is it that, not every little change is sent to the actual DOM and that a collection of those changes (batch) are sent all at once?
How does the virtual DOM decide when to send the batch update?

Comment: "*sends a batch update to the real DOM*". This sounds so easy to do. Try doing this in a real world large application with just JS/jQuery. Make 100(s) different people work on it over many years. End result would be very... *interesting* (I work on such things on a daily basis)

Comment: This is what I read in a tutorial